# Magento 2 Rest API Products Price

Tags: magento2, api

Is Tax included or excluded from *Price in Rest API Products* when backend settings:

*Sales/Tax/ Catalog Prices: I**ncluding Tax*** (This sets whether catalog prices entered from Magento Admin include tax.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Included**.

The [tax configuration documentation](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/sales/tax.html) is not very descriptive around this, however this setting tells Magento whether or not you have already manually added tax onto your product prices, or if Magento should add the tax on at the time of sale.

When you are using the REST API, you are accessing/updating the product catalog data. If you have the setting set to "Including Tax", Magento will assume the catalog data has the tax included already.

Comment: Ok so if I use Rest API update the Price, tax should be included? And if I fetch it will be included? Do you know where I can find any references/docs for that?

Comment: I've updated my answer and added a link to the documentation (which is not so descriptive). Hope this helps.